# Why the EditText shows a black frame when focused on devices that greater than 7.0

Tags: android

this is my Edittext, it works well on all the devices that below 7.0. all of the things are ok, the following capture is good.

[good man, click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYBrJ.jpg)

but when the edittext get focus, it gets a black frame, the color became more and more black automatically, it seems like the edittext redraw but have not erased the background. To the end, it has become like the following image:

[image]

so, let me summy all the clues:

1. only occur greater than android 7.0
2. the shape is rounded rectangle
3. focused (when i touch other views, the black frame disappear, it would appear in a while later.)

the EditText layout attribute is shown below:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/contact_type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/complain_edit"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
    android:hint="@string/text_contact_number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

and the @drawable/complain_edit is mention to the following lines of my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="33.33dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="33.33dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="33.33dp"
        android:topRightRadius="33.33dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="0.33dp"
        android:color="#4D000000"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it does'nt work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try @drawable/complain_edit as

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape androidhape="rectangle">
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="33.33dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="33.33dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="33.33dp"
            android:topRightRadius="33.33dp"/>
        <solid
            android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="1px"
    android:left="1px"
    android:right="1px"
    android:top="1px">
    <shape androidhape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="33.33dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="33.33dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="33.33dp"
            android:topRightRadius="33.33dp"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="1px"
            android:color="#4D000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```